# Pipenv: Multiple Environments

Tags: python, virtualenv, pipenv

Right now I'm using `virtualenv` and just switching over to `Pipenv`. Today in virtualenv I load in different environment variables and settings depending on whether I'm in `development`, `production`, or `testing`by setting `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to `myproject.settings.development`, `myproject.settings.production`, and `myproject.settings.testing`.

I'm aware that I can set an `.env` file, but how can I have multiple versions of that `.env` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create different `.env` files with different prefixes depending on the environment, such as `production.env` or `testing.env`.  With `pipenv`, you can use the `PIPENV_DONT_LOAD_ENV=1` environment variable to prevent `pipenv shell` from automatically exporting the `.env` file and combine this with `export $(cat .env | xargs)`.

`export $(cat production.env | xargs) && PIPENV_DONT_LOAD_ENV=1 pipenv shell` would configure your environment variables for production and then start a shell in the virtual environment.

Comment: There is no need to `export $(cat .env | xargs)`: one can just specify what "version" of the environment variables file to load as specified here: https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/#automatic-loading-of-env. In the case at hand one could do `PIPENV_DOTENV_LOCATION=prod.env/test.env pipenv shell`. The advantage of this approach is that your env variables aren't kept in the shell upon exiting, which otherwise would be the case in your example.

Comment: Besides the previous comment about using `PIPENV_DOTENV_LOCATION`, and the brokeness in the presence of characters which would cause field splitting, globbing, and so on, you can also simplify this method to just: `$(cat .env | xargs) PIPENV_DONT_LOAD_ENV=1 pipenv shell`, and thereby avoid leaking exported variables into all commands after this one.

Comment: Actually I got so focused on my prior points that I totally forgot that I think you can simplify this further: you don't need `| xargs` at all, because in Bourne-like shells newlines in substituted output will work *just like spaces* - they cause field splitting (unless you've messed with your shell's field splitting, such as by setting the `IFS` variable), but they will never be treated as statement separators.

Answer (score 10):

I'm far from a Python guru, but one solution I can think of would be to create [Pipenv scripts](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/#custom-script-shortcuts) that run shell scripts to change the [`PIPENV_DOTENV_LOCATION`](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/#automatic-loading-of-env) and run your startup commands.

Example Pipfile scripts:

```
[scripts]
development = "./scripts/development.sh"
```

development.sh Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
PIPENV_DOTENV_LOCATION=/path/to/.development_env pipenv run python test.py
```

Then run `pipenv run development`